# Access Reverse Proxy from Docker container on Service Fabric on dev machine

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to use the Reverse proxy to communicate between services Docker containers in Service Fabric. 
I have verified that the reverse proxy is working using the following:

> var url = http://mymachine:19081/applicationName/servicename/api/values
>
> var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

However, running inside the container I call the above link and get a HttpRequestException: The operation timed out

I have also tried my local machine ip address and this has the same problem. It seems like something is blocking traffic from the container to my local machine.

Can anyone point me the right direction of what I can try next? Or this is scenario not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found is that switching Wifi connections prevents communication to certain ports. When I restart machine or Service Fabric, I am now able to access the reverse proxy